# Can I change the default match method in Excel from "Less than" to "Exact match"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, vlookup

By default, MS-Excel uses `1 - Less than` as match method in functions like `vlookup` and `match`.

Apparently Excel assumes the data is sorted and if the value I am looking for is missing, the value just before it is about just as good. That is fine if I need to lookup the temperature at 10:15 in a hourly list of temperatures.

However, at the office, that is rarely the case. For instance, if I want to add the name of the account holders to a list of accounts, but my list of customers is incomplete, I don't want the name of customer number `1234566` on an account owned by customer `1234567`. I want to see the error!

It is annoying to change the match method to `0 - Exact match`, and worse I, and my colleagues, sometimes forget it and have wrong results, so is there a way t change the default?

Comment: When the 4th argument is `FALSE`, VLOOKUP returns `#N/A` when no matching value is found, or whatever is its value. Or are you looking for a way of not specifying this argument?

Comment: I think OP iu asking to set 0 as default. But is to lazy to complate the formula. Solution is easy, learn to always use all parameters. And know whwne it will work or not (e.g. it will even fail on precise matches for long numbers (around 18 digits).

Comment: Correct Hennes, harrymc should read a question before replying. And Hennes, what is wrong with looking for a more efficient, less error prone way of working?

Comment: @DirkHorsten learning how to write a formula properly makes it less error prone

Comment: I don't see an issue with wanting to set the default to be the option that everyone uses, it has caught me out a couple of times when I was hurrying or returning after not using excel for a long time. Saying that I do not know of a way to achieve that end except to write your own User Defined Function in VBA where it utilises vlookup or whichever you are interested in but sets it to false.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work, copy into a module and use MyVlookup instead of Vlookup.

```
Function MyVlookup(LookUpVal As Range, SchRnge As Range, RtrnCol As Long)
MyVlookup = Application.VLookup(LookUpVal, SchRnge, RtrnCol, False)
End Function
```

You can use the same idea for other functions that are irritating. Although I have not been able to get the vlookup to fail in a quick test and am wondering if MS have already tackled this in the latest version of excel.

Comment: That's worth an up-vote, but I will not adapt it: 1) I would have to explain my colleagues. 2.1) I would have to macro enable all my spreadsheets. 2.2) or if I put the function in my hidden Personal Macro Workbook and convince my colleagues to do the same.